# Setting ethernet as "mobile"?

Tags: opensuse, network-interface

I'm behind a very slow Internet connection most of the time.  OpenSuSE TumbleWeed occasionally likes to go suck down all my bandwidth at really inopportune times to check for updates.  I've got it set at the max time, which is a month.  I've previously pursued trying to turn off the updater completely, but that has been a losing battle.

There's also an option to have it not try to update when on a mobile connection.  My super slow primary Internet seems like a good use of that...  How can I tag my ethernet as "mobile" to keep the system from trying to update that way?  That would allow the updates to still try and run when I'm on the road and someplace with fast wifi.

Comment: Sounds like opensuse is being a bit too clever here. Since updates must be scheduled, you'd have to just find where that job is scheduled, and remove that scheduled job, and update manually when you have access to a faster connection. It's either going to be a cron job or some form of systemd cron, no idea how opensuse does it. I prefer distributions that leave such things in my hands, this sounds like something opensuse added relatively recently since forced automatic upgrades should be easily controllable. See if you have apper installed, disable check for updates, set to never.